# Extract latitudes and longitudes from a government database

Tags: latitude-longitude, esri-geodatabase, extract, government

I'm trying to get the latitudes and longitudes of various data points on the [Alberta Water License viewer](http://waterlicences.alberta.ca/). The mapping tool has the points displayed on it, and I'm able to click on them and get more information, but the only way that I can get the Lat/Long of the points currently is to open Google Earth and try and match the location exactly and manually write out the Lat/Long from that.

Is there some way I can extract this information more easily?

I don't have much GIS experience.

Comment: All the underlying data is on the ArcGIS REST Services [Farm9] https://maps.alberta.ca/genesis_tokenauth/rest/services but seek permission to use. You will not get very far as token/header controlled.

Answer (score 1):

The department hosting this doesn't appear to have released such detailed information online. It may be for privacy reasons. You can try to reach out to them directly to determine whether the information is available for your project or under specific data use agreements.  Here is the webpage with their contact information: https://www.alberta.ca/contact.cfm